# SUM within CASE WHEN Statement in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I have a query like this, O_ID data type is VARCHAR, f_units datatype is Number

I did below to avoid divisor by zero error, when i do this I am still getting the error **ORA-01476: divisor is equal to zero** when I add sum for whole case when statement then it says Function too deeply closed.

```
select O_ID,SUM(F_UNITS),
CASE WHEN SUM(F_UNITS) <> 0 THEN sum(cast(f_units as float)) / sum(cast(sum(f_units ) as float)) over (partition by O_ID) ELSE 0 END
from myfacttable
```

How can I handle divisor 0 error in this scenariao?

Comment: What are you trying to do? It doesn't seem to make sense to divide a higher number by a smaller one here. E.g. you've got the overall sum divided by the sum over a partition by `o_id`. I think you want the reverse?

Comment: I am trying to do a market share calculation formula is Total F_units / Total F_units of O_ID, where my O_ID is my outlet, Its like market share for each outlet..,

Comment: Please edit the SELECT statement in your question so it's valid. You have a `CASE` expression which isn't terminated - there's no `END` for the `CASE`. Thanks.

Comment: Also you can't select `o_id` and `sum(f_units)` without grouping by `o_id`. But adding that changes the logic of whatever you are trying to do in the `sum(cast(f_units as float)) / sum(etc)` expression. Some test data would help a lot.

Comment: The standard pattern is to wrap the divisor expression in `nullif(yourdivisor,0)`, which will return nulls where a value can't be computed. I'd post that as an answer but I can't tell what the query is meant to be doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you are checking for when `SUM(F_UNITS) <> 0`, but you're dividing by `sum(cast(sum(f_units ) as float)) over (partition by O_ID)` which is an entirely different value.

Change your conditional clause to `sum(cast(sum(f_units ) as float)) over (partition by O_ID) <> 0` and you'll likely have better luck.